When a taut string is plucked, what will be the direction of the transverse wave's propagation?
Intuitively, I'd guess that the direction of propagation depends on where you pluck the string, namely which half of the string.
In the case of a stringed instrument, this guess of mine would effectively translate as the following

If you pluck the string near the nut of the instrument, the propagation direction will be $\textbf{n}$, where $\textbf{n}$ is parallel to the string
Conversely, if you pluck the string near the bridge of the instrument, the propagation direction will be $-\textbf{n}$

However, this intuition of mine seems to run into an issue: what happens if you pluck the string precisely at the midpoint of the string's length?


if you pluck the string precisely at the midpoint of the string's length?

There will be 2 waves, propagating in opposite directions with transverse amplitude = plucked-amplitude/2

And if I pluck the string near the bridge, will the wave propagate in the direction of from-bridge-to-nut or in the direction of from-nut-to-bridge? Once this is answered, I'll mark your answer as accepted. I'd imagine the answer is the former (from-bridge-to-nut) but I just want to be absolutely sure

@SimonM The answer is that you do the normal mode i.e. almost Fourier, decomposition of the plucking initial function, and then note that this is made of waves in both positive and negative $k$ components; the sign difference tells you which direction it moves, and the decomposition tells you the amplitude, i.e. the relative importance of each contribution.

Wherever you pluck the string, you will create two instantaneous wave packets - combinations of waves of many different wavelengths - one travelling in each direction along the string. However, once the two wavepackets are reflected from each end of the string, they will interfere with each other. As a result, all components of these wavepackets with wavelengths that are not an integer division of twice the effective string length will quickly die out, leaving a standing wave with components that are harmonics of the string length.
The relative amplitudes of different harmonics will depend on where you pluck the string, leading to different timbres (and the body of the instrument will amplify some harmonics more than others too), but the basic spectrum of possible harmonics is independent of where you pluck the string.

If we take the instrument away and deal with just an individual taut string, then the timbre would be symmetric with respect to either half of the string, right? That is, the timbre that results from plucking the string $x$ millimeters from end A of the string would be the very same timbre that results from plucking the string $x$ millimeters from end B of the string, right? I don't see why there would be an asymmetry there, so that's why that's my intuition.
